# How to set width to "fit-content" with additional width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how I can set the width of an element to `fit-content`, but I also want to add some more width. I cannot use padding, I only want to use width. Maybe something like `width: fit-content + 50px` or something like that?

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
.element{
   width: fit-content + 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Could you not create a chide element to provide the extra width, then set the parent to `fit-content`?

Comment: Not possible. You're looking for `calc()` but you can't combine intrinsic and extrinsic units. As in, `calc(fit-content + 50px)` isn't valid CSS. Some kind of padding or margin is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to use `calc()` to combine intrinsic and extrinsic units. The only option here is to use padding. Since you said you cannot apply padding to your element, you would need to create a child element to carry these styles.

Here's an example (I've added background to each to visualize)

```css
.acharb-outer {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: #ffd166;
}

.acharb-inner {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  background: #ef476f;
}

span {
  background: #06d6a0;
}
```

```html
<div class="acharb-outer">
  <div class="acharb-inner">
    <span>Quisque ut dolor gravida.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="acharb-outer">
  <div class="acharb-inner">
    <span>Fabio vel iudice vincam, sunt in culpa qui officia.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="acharb-outer">
  <div class="acharb-inner">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```